# Tried to append span into list appendchild(span) it is throwing an error?

Tags: javascript

I'm the biginer . I have tried to append span into the list items which i have been dynamically created.But its not working. Within the function this code is working But Outside its not working...
Listcheck[i].appendChild(span); its not appending properly

```js
var listcheck = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
for (var i = 0; i <= listcheck.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  span.textContent = "X";
  span.className += "closeicon";
  listcheck[i].appendChild(span);
}

function searchinput() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputtext = document.getElementById("client_course").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputtext);
  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(t);
}
```

```html
 <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainstyle.css">
<script src="JS/todo_JS.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
<div class="main">
<div class="checkportion">
<div class="chk_b">
<ul id="myUL">
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" class="check_class" id="check1">
<label for="check1">Javascript</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="search_portion">
<Input type="text" id="client_course">
<input type="Submit" Value="add" onclick="searchinput()">
</div>

</div>
</header>

</html>
```

Comment: Element with `id="myUL"` does not exist. So `getElementById("myUL")` returns `undefined`. So you're trying to do `undefined.appendChild(li)`, so you're getting an error `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined`. Oh yeah. It's all coming together.

Comment: Did you `console.log` the value of `listcheck`? Does it return an HTML collection? Are you adding your script at the bottom of the `body` element?  The error you are getting is either because the element does not exist or you are trying to access the element before it's rendered and so, it does not exist. Check carefully where the `li` gets added to your page and that should help you fix this.

Comment: I have been console.log the listcheck HTML elements are appear is console. when i appending that time only I am facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first block of code must not perform when script is loaded
   because no one li in body at that time. Lis are added only when user
   click button.
2. Where is your client_source?

   ```
    var inputtext = document.getElementById("client_course").value;
   ```

3.Where is your MyUL?

```
document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
```

4.Your function searchinput creates li but does not append it to document. Therefore here:

```
listcheck[i].appendChild(span);
```

you have an error. listcheck[i] is undefined because no one li is appended.

## UPD

It throws an error because this script performs one time, it is not a function that performs after some actions.

1. Page is loaded
2. Script performs (but function does not, because it performs only
   after click on button)
   3. Your first block does not see any LI so it
   is undefined Solutions:

   - Create event and dispatch it to your
     element
     (developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)
   - Use MutationObserver

Comment: Ok Thanks. Previously I didn't add the full HTML.. Now I have been added my Full HTML . Pls check

Comment: Do not you want to put your block of code inside searchinput?

Comment: If I add this block of code inside the Function its working(But without for loop) If i add it listcheck[i] its not working thorow an error. .But My question is  why it is not working outside of the function

Comment: It throws an error because this script performs one time, it is not a function that performs after some actions. 
1. Page is loaded
2. Script performs (but function does not, because it performs only after click on button)
3. Your first block does not see any LI so it is undefined

Solutions:
- Create event and dispatch it to your element (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)
- Use MutationObserver

Comment: Ok thnk you. I will check